# Sufficient conditions for a subspace $E$ of a topological vector space $X$ to be dense, in terms of continuous linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I prove the following result:

> Let a [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) $X$ be   with an increasing set of seminorms $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ and $E\subseteq X$ be a subspace. $E$ satisfies the condition that $\ker f=X$ whenever $f\in X^*$, $E\subseteq \ker f$. Here $\ker$ denotes the null space of a linear operator and $X^*$ is the continuous dual of $X$. The topology on $X$ is generated by open balls of **all** radius in **all** seminorms $p_m$. Then, $E$ is dense in $X$.

*Proof.* Suppose not. Then there exists $x_0\in X, m\in \mathbb Z, \epsilon>0$ such that the ball $B(x_0,m;\epsilon)=\{\xi\in X:p_m(x-\xi)<\epsilon\}$ is disjoint from $E$. Consequently, $B(x_0,n;\epsilon)\cap E=\emptyset$ for all $n\geq m$.

Define $\tilde p_n(x)=\sup_{y\in E} p_n(x-y)$. It's easy to verify that $\tilde p_n$ is a seminorm. Define in the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x_0$ the linear functional $f_n$ by $f_n(kx_0)=k\tilde p_n(x_0)$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists an extension to $X^*$, such that $|f_n(x)|\leq \tilde p_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$. In particular, $\tilde p_m(y)=0$ for all $y\in E$, so $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in E$. Contradiction. $\square$

Note that the space $X$ doesn't even have to be Hausdorff. Is my proof correct?

Now, I am thinking about the following things. Let $X$ be a general topological vector space, and let $E$ be a subspace such that whenever $f\in X^*$ and $E\subseteq \ker f$, $\ker f=X$.

1. If $X$ is Hausdorff, is it always the case that $E$ is dense in $X$?
2. It seems that it is not even necessary for $X$ to be Hausdorff. Actually, even if the topology is trivial, we may conclude $E$ is dense. If we have the discrete topology on $X$, the every linear functional is continuous, so we may also conclude that $E$ is dense.

**In the end, under what circumstances is the condition "whenever $f\in X^*$ and $E\subseteq \ker f$, $\ker f=X$" sufficient for $E$ to be dense?**

Comment: You treat the fixed vector $x$ as a variable, and you give two arguments for $p_n$ when by definition it only has one. To prove it correctly, suppose $X$ is a normed space and that $E$ is a non-dense subspace.  Then we can find $x\in X$ and $\rho>0$ such that the $\|\cdot\|$-$\rho$-neighborhood of $x$ is disjoint from $E$.  Define the linear functional $f:\mathbb{K}x+E\to\mathbb{K}$ by $f(ax+e)=a$.  Verify that $f$ is continuous using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition with $\delta=\epsilon\rho$, then extend it to $f\in X^*$ via HB. In case $X$ is Frechet or general TVS, more work is required.

Comment: In particular, you'll need to show that Hahn-Banach extension of **continuous** functionals works for a Frechet or TVS setting.

Comment: @BenW Is the proof correct now? I have edited it. Why do we need to consider $\mathbb K x +E$? I believe the $f$ will be automatically zero on $E$ once we define it on $\text{span} x_0$ and extend it to $X$.

Comment: @BenW Could you provide a reference for Hahn Banach in general TVS? Thank you.

Comment: @BenW Sorry for the errors. Typing incorrectly.

Comment: The version of Hahn-Banach you're using gives a linear functional, but you still need to show that it's continuous. Instead you might want to try some version of the HB-separation theorem, which does guarantee continuity. See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem

Comment: @BenW I see...but that's going to be difficult. Actually, I don't exactly know what could be proven and what are false. Is it true for general TVS?

Comment: @BenW Using the theorem as stated in wikipedia for closed set $\overline E$ and compact set $\{x_0\}$, we get a continuous functional $f$ which is bounded below in $\overline E$. That forces $f$ to be zero on $E$. On the other hand, $f$ cannot be zero on $X$. Is it really that simple?

Comment: In the locally convex case yes. So no need for frechet.

Comment: @BenW Do you have reference for more results like that?